# PHP script running incredibly slow - writing to file in batches

Tags: php, append

I have a script that pulls out aprox 5000 rows of data in 1000 batches and appends to a file.  However, it takes way over an hour and I have noticed that the number of rows in the generated file is way more than $countProds and so must be doing something wrong somewhere.  Anyone any ideas?

```
$startTime = time();    
$productLimit = 5000; 

//if file already exists then delete file so can write new file
if (file_exists($file)){
    unlink($file);
}           

$datafeed_separator = "|";          

$productsObj = new Products($db, $KeeperID);                    

//find out how many items keeper has
$countProds = $productsObj->countShopKeeperProducts();

//limit the amount of products
if ($countProds > $productLimit){$countProds = $productLimit; }     

$productBatchLimit = 500;   

//create new file
$fh = fopen($file, 'a');        

$counter = 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $countProds; $i += $productBatchLimit) {

    $limit = $productBatchLimit*$counter;

    $products = $productsObj->getShopKeeperProducts($i, $limit);

    foreach($products as $product){
        $prod_id = $product['prod_id'];
        $prod_name = str_replace("|", " ", $product['productName']);
        $prod_desc = trim($product['productDescription']);
        $prod_image = $productsObj->getImageURL();  

        $txt .= 
        $prod_id . $datafeed_separator . 
        $prod_name . $datafeed_separator . 
        $prod_desc . $datafeed_separator . 
        $prod_image . $datafeed_separator . 

    }   
    fwrite($fh, $txt);
    $counter++;     
}
fclose($fh);

header ("Content-Type:text/plain;charset=utf-8");
include ($file);    
$endTime = time();
echo  "Total time to generate results: ".($endTime - $startTime)." seconds.\n";
```

Comment: where are you getting the data from?

Comment: what happens inside `Products::getShopKeeperProducts` and `Products::getImageUrl`? This is almost guaranteed to be your bottleneck.

Comment: You should start with tracking time spent for one cycle of foreach $products, and one cycle of for $i, then you should be able to estimate which part is time consuming

Comment: I am getting the datafrom an mssql database.  Products::getShopKeeperProductsruns the mssql query to pull out the data in batches.  eg.  $prod_qry = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT id, productName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row  FROM products WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE shopkeeper='$this->shopkeeper'  ) a WHERE row > $start and row <= $limit";   Products::getImageUrl simply builds a string URL so this cannot be causing any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your other methods (`getShopKeeperProducts` / `getImageURL`)its difficult to pinpoint the exact problem ... but what I always do when i have these kinds of problems is time each section of my code ... try this :

```
// before a method
echo "Starting method a".PHP_EOL;
$start = time();
// do something
// after your method
echo "Done processing method a, time = " . (time() - $start) .PHP_EOL;
```

This will output the time in seconds to process `// do something` - this should give you a nice list of times and you can quickly see where your issues are rather than just timing the whole method / class / file

Comment: I have noticed that instead of bringing out out batches of 1000's for each batch, it brings out 1000 or the first batch, 2000 for the 2nd etc.  This is probably why it is slow and the total number of ourputted rows is a lot more than the total number of actual products.  Can anyone spot where in my code is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `for()` loop that can run up to 500 times (`$productBatchLimit = 500;`).

Inside the `for()` loop, you have a `foreach()` loop. The `foreach()` loop can run up to the amount of values inside `$products`.

The amount of values inside `$products` (assuming the `getShopKeepProducts()` method works as it should) is decided with your following line of code:
`$limit = $productBatchLimit*$counter`

We know that `$productBatchLimit = 500;` and `$counter` = amount of times the `for()` loop has run by the time we start the `foreach()` loop.

Going through the `for()` loop 1 time will run the code inside the `foreach()` loop up to 500 times.

Going through the `for()` loop 500 times will run the code inside the `foreach()` loop up to 62.625.500 times.

To fix this, you could change `$products = $productsObj->getShopKeeperProducts($i, $limit);` to `$products = $productsObj->getShopKeeperProducts($i, $productLimit);` and delete `$limit = $productBatchLimit*$counter`. Every time the `for()` loop starts, the `foreach()` loop is now limited to run 5000 times.

Going through the `for()` loop 500 times will now run the code inside the `foreach()` loop up to a maximum of 2.500.000 times (500 `for()` * 5000 `foreach()`) instead of the current maximum of 62.625.500 times.